# An infinite game possibly due to Ernst Specker

Tags: infinite-games

I have a vague memory of an infinite game due to Ernst Specker with
the following properties:

(1) It is a two-person perfect information game, where the players
move alternately.

(2) The possible moves depend only on the current position.

(3) There is no winning strategy where each move is based only on
the current position

(4) There is a winning strategy (for one of the players) if the
strategy uses the current position and the history of previous moves.

Can someone provide a reference or explanation for this game?

Comment: Does the payoff depend on the sequence of positions, or just on the "limit" (in some sense) of the sequence of positions?

Comment: It's not the one you're looking for but Gabriel Debs gave an example of a topological space whose Banach–Mazur game has a winning "historical" strategy but no winning "positional" strategy ("tactic").

Comment: @bof If the payoff depends on the history, then there are easy examples: let first player win if he plays his red piece on move 17 and only then, but otherwise he loses. If the position doesn't tell him the turn number, then he can't have a position-based winning strategy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know about the game attributed to Specker, but here is a
simple game with your desired features.

Let us call it the **Chocolatier's game**. There are two players,
the Chocolatier and the Glutton. To begin play, the Chocolatier
serves up finitely many unique and exquisite chocolate creations on
a platter, and then the Glutton chooses one of them to eat. Play
continues — at each stage the Chocolatier adds finitely many
additional chocolates to the platter, and the Glutton consumes one
of those available. The excess uneaten chocolates accumulate on the platter as play progresses.

After infinite play, the Glutton wins if every single chocolate
that was served was eventually consumed. Otherwise, the Chocolatier
wins.

The Glutton can easily win simply by paying attention to the order
in which the chocolates were added, and consuming them in that
order. If only finitely many chocolates are added at each stage, the Glutton should simply make sure to consume them before moving on to the
chocolates that were added at later stages.

Indeed, the Glutton can win even if the Chocolatier places countably many chocolates on each turn. At turn $n=2^k(2m+1)$, let the Glutton eat the $k$th
chocolate added at stage $m$, if any, and otherwise eat
arbitrarily.

But what about strategies that depend only on the current position,
that is, the assortment of chocolates on the platter?

In one sense, it is easy to see that there can be no such winning
strategy for the Glutton. If the Glutton will choose a particular
chocolate from a given assortment, then let the Chocolatier simply
replace it with an identical chocolate type on the next move, and again on all subsequent moves. If
the strategy does not know the history, then the Glutton will
choose it again every time, and the other chocolates will never be
eaten.

Perhaps it makes a more interesting game, however, to say that the Chocolatier loses if chocolate types are ever repeated. And for this version of the game, there are some interesting things to say.

If there are only countably many chocolate types available in all,
then again the Glutton has a winning strategy that depends only on
the current assortment on offer. Namely, the Glutton should fix an
enumeration of the possible chocolate types that might appear, and
at each stage select the chocolate that appears earliest in this
order — it is the tastiest-looking chocolate as defined by
that priority. With this strategy he will succeed in eating all the
chocolates, because at the limit, if any chocolate was left, there
would have to be a tastiest-looking one (earliest in the
enumeration), and this would have been eaten once the finitely many
tastier chocolates had been consumed.

If the Chocolatier were uncountably creative, however, and able to
serve up uncountably many different chocolate types, then this
argument breaks down. Indeed, in this case I claim there is no
winning strategy for the Glutton that depends only on the chocolate
assortment on offer. And indeed, there is no such strategy that
works even if we should insist that the Chocolatier present an
assortment only of size two at each stage.

To see this, suppose the Glutton will follow a fixed strategy that
selects a particular chocolate to eat from amongst any two
chocolates.

For any given chocolate $c$, if there are infinitely many others
$d_n$ that would be preferred to it by the strategy, if presented
as a pair $\{c,d_n\}$, then the Chocolatier can present these pairs
$\{c,d_0\}$, $\{c,d_1\}$, $\{c,d_2\}$, in turn. At each stage,
$d_n$ would be consumed and the Chocolatier can present
$\{c,d_{n+1}\}$. In the end, the inferior chocolate $c$ would never
have been selected and so the Chocolatier will win.

So if this is a winning strategy for the Glutton, then we may
assume that every chocolate is preferred to all but finitely many
of the others. But this is simply impossible with an uncountable
set. To see this, take any countably infinite set of chocolates and
close under the finite witnesses of strictly preferred chocolates.
One thereby constructs a countably infinite set $D$ of chocolates
so that any chocolate in $D$ is preferred to any chocolate not in
$D$. Since there were uncountably many chocolate types, there is
some $c\notin D$. This contradicts our assumption that there are
only finitely many chocolates preferred to a given chocolate.

Let me remark that in the version of the game where we do not allow
the Chocolatier to repeat chocolate types (as opposed to saying that this is allowed, but causes the Chocolatier to lose), then we should really
include the list of already-consumed chocolates as part of the
position, and this complicates the arguments above. (I asked a followup question about this at [The Chocolatier's game](https://mathoverflow.net/q/401151/1946).) I suspect but
do not yet know that the Glutton can have no winning strategy that
depends only on these more general kinds of positions in the uncountable case.

Comment: One can also present the game in the form of a bag of marbles, with one player adding finitely marbles at each turn and the other removing just one.

Comment: So is it clear that for some version neither player has a winning strategy with each move based only on the current position?

Comment: Since the Glutton has a winning strategy that uses the history, the Chocolatier cannot have any kind of winning strategy, especially not a special strategy that depends only on the current position.

Comment: Another isomorphic version: the attacker adds finitely many more time bombs (to explode at infinity), but the defuser can only defuse one bomb each turn. Defuser wins if every bomb is defused.

Comment: There are two-person games where it's claimed by mathematicians I respect that both players have winning strategies: see [Lion and Man -- Can Both Win?](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2524) by Bollobás, Leader, and Walters. This may depend on a non-finiteness property which doesn't apply to the particular game your comment refers to.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That kind of continuous strategy phenomenon can't arise for a game proceeding in well-ordered discrete steps like this, since here we can always play any two strategies against each other. In the paper you cite, however, it doesn't always make sense to play two strategies against each other, and this seems to be required for the situation you describe, of both players having winning strategies.

Comment: Without getting into continuous games there are simple examples of games of length $\omega^*$ where both players have winning strategies.

Comment: "suppose the Glutton will follow a fixed strategy ... then the Chocolatier can present these pairs {,0}, {,1}, {,2}, in turn" – This requires that the Chocolatier knows the Glutton's strategy, doesn't it? (I think we should require that neither player knows the other's strategy. Otherwise, both could try to adapt their strategy to the other's strategy, and we'd run into paradoxes...)

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica No, that is incorrect. If you are claiming to have a winning strategy, then I can know what it is, for the purpose of proving that it doesn't work. If there is any logically possible play (including those built under the assumption that you would follow it) according to which your strategy doesn't work, then it isn't actually a winning strategy.

Comment: In particular, I don't believe that there are any paradoxes at all in this vein. If you have a truly winning strategy, then it shouldn't matter whether anyone knows how you will play. Otherwise, it wasn't actually winning, if there is a play that defeats it.

Comment: In other words, part of what we mean by a winning strategy is that if someone truly has a winning strategy, then they can announce to the world that they intend to play according to it, and they will still win every time. (Specifically, a strategy is a function telling the player what move to make next, given the previous play, and a winning strategy is one with the property that every play of the game that accords with it is winning for that player.)

Comment: I see. I don't really know anything about infinite games, and I'm not a mathematician but a software engineer, so I guess I was thinking about this too "constructively", in a sense. In this case: We can prove that for every alleged winning strategy sG for G, there exists a strategy sC(sG) for C which defeats it. The probablity that C will actually play that strategy may be zero (because C doesn't know sG and thus can't choose sC(sG)), but that doesn't matter. Correct?

Comment: I think that isn't the right way to look at it. A given strategy is winning, if all plays that conform with it win. It has nothing to do with liklihood or anything other than logical possibility. For every simply definable game, one of the players will have such a winning strategy. But with the axiom of choice, you can construct games played with natural numbers for which neither player has a winning strategy. In fact, even without the axiom of choice, it is a theorem that there are games (on some uncountable set) for which neither player has a winning strategy.

Comment: I've been scratching my head trying to make sense of this game. I feel there is something basic missing in its description. If the chocolatier can add more than 1 chocolate to the platter each turn, how can the glutton ever win? When you talk about 'finitely many', do you mean per turn or overall?

Comment: @Ingolifs The Chocolatier adds finitely many delicacies each turn, so the total on the platter is also finite at each turn, but it could be growing rapidly. Nevertheless, the Glutton can still win. Suppose the chocolate morsels are numbered like the natural numbers (but they are not necessarily placed in order)---then let the Glutton simply take the lowest-numbered one each turn. Eventually, he will eat every one of them, no matter how many accumulate on each turn. The other arguments show that if he knows the history, then we can drop the natural-number assumption.

Comment: @MarkS Thanks, I have now fixed that.

Comment: If the Glutton knows in advance which chocolates will be presented (which seems reasonable to assume for a perfect information game) but not at what turn a chocolate will be presented, then he or she needs only order them in a sequence $C_1,C_2,\dots$ and choose the least chocolate that is on the platter. It is not necessary to know the previous history. Is there a different game that doesn't have this defect?

Comment: @Richard, the game with an uncountably creative Chocolatier doesn't have that defect---if there are uncountably many chocolate types, then even when only two are served each turn, there can be no winning strategy for the Glutton that doesn't depend on the history.